# How to do effective spatial joins using spark v2.0 and python?

Tags: python, spatial-join

I need to do spatial joins and KNN joins on big geolocalised dataset.

They are stored as pySpark RDDs.

I've been looking for libraries to do so, but couldn't find any that fits my needs:

- compatible with Spark 2
- compatible with pySpark
- Allowing to do fast spatial joins

Have anybody succeed to do geo-analysis with pySpark ?

Would using Spark in combination with shapely functions or geoPandas dataframes be a decent solution ?

PS: Libraries I looked :

- [Magellan](https://github.com/harsha2010/magellan) => not compatible with Spark2
- [SpatialSpark](http://simin.me/projects/spatialspark/) => neither
- [GeoSpark](http://geospark.datasyslab.org/) => not compatible with pySpark
- [LocationSpark](https://github.com/merlintang/SpatialSpark) => neither

Comment: Magellan now seems to be compatible with Spark2 ! I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: did you ever figure out an answer to this with pyspark?

Comment: No, but I didn't really try again either